# Call batch file which calls another batch file using the second ones directory as working directory

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

Assuming I have a batch file (start.bat) in C:\ with this lines :

```
start cmd /k call dir1\dir2\1.bat
start cmd /k call dir3\dir4\2.bat
start cmd /k call dir5\dir6\3.bat
```

Inside 1,2,3.batch I have

```
call mvn clean install
```

thus I need 1,2,3.batch to run in the directory where they are located. Other solutions I have found use `pushd` or `~dp0` and I can't get it to work with start.bat because when run they still execute in C:\ (the current working dir of start.bat)

The structure is this:

```
C:\
    dir1
        dir2
    dir3
        dir4
    dir5
        dir6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indicate in the start command what the current active folder should be for the started process

```
start "[started in dir2]" /d "dir1\dir2" cmd /k 1.bat
```

Comment: it works thank you. a small half-OT question. can another batch file start start.bat and wait for it to complete? like startstart.bat (start /wait call start.bat)? I have a bunch of different batch files which should run in sequence, waiting for the previous one to finish

Comment: @sceiler, if one batch file directly invokes another batch file, the execution flow is transfered to the called and does not return to the caller. Use `call child.bat` so when the called file ends, execution continues in the caller.